# Лучший способ сделать checkbox/radio из изображения

Tags: css, input, stylus

Использую следующий код для получения `checkbox` из изображения:

```
input[type='checkbox']
    display none

input[type='checkbox'] + label  
    width 100px
    height 10px
    position relative

    &:before
        content ''
        position absolute
        left 0
        width 10px
        height 10px
        background embedurl('checkbox.png') 0 -1px no-repeat
```

Проблема в том, что не особо легко позиционировать квадратик элемента относительно его надписи (`label`), или наоборот, особо учитывая границы смещения (как бы `margin`).

Еще проблема возникает, когда есть список `ul` из таких элементов, в котором произвольно "прыгают" выше, или ниже эти квадратики:

```
ul
    height 100%
    columns 3
    column-gap 40.5px
    column-fill auto
    padding-top 5px

li
    box-sizing border-box
    width 250px
    padding-bottom 9px
    border 0
    list-style none
```

Comment: а вопрос в чем конкретно?

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko
Вопрос в том, как убрать проблемы позицыонирования метки и квадратика...

Comment: Сделай код запускаемым хоть, примерчик на codepen.io хотя бы...

Answer (score 2):

Вас это интересует?

```css
ul {
  max-width: 300px;
  list-style: none;
}
.label {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.input {
  display: none;
}
.text {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.text:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.text:after {
  content: 'x';
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 3px;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
.input:checked + .text:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-0">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-0"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-1">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-1"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-2">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-2"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-3">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-3"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-4">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-4"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-5">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-5"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-6">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-6"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-7">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-7"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-8">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-8"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-9">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-9"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-10">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-10"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-11">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-11"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label" for="input-12">
      <input class="input" type="checkbox" id="input-12"/>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla, odio, error! Consequuntur cupiditate, iure sequi rerum illo eveniet ipsa est beatae! Ab esse animi corporis reiciendis sit quibusdam earum incidunt.</div>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```